# Breadcrumbs links not showing correct url

Tags: codeigniter

I am creating some bread crumbs for my folders. When I click on the 2nd bread crumb link it does not go to the correct URL

The previous URL shows "test"

```
http://localhost/project/admin/common/test?directory=test/sub
```

It should show

```
http://localhost/project/admin/common/test?directory=test
```

**Inspector Output**

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="http://localhost/project/admin/common/test">Catalog</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/project/admin/common/test?directory=test/sub">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/project/admin/common/test?directory=test/sub">sub</a></li>
</ul>
```

**On view**

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

> **Question**: How can I make sure the previous URL to shows the before folder correct URL.

I generate my breadcrumbs on my controller

```
$data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

$data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
    'text' => 'Catalog',
    'href' => base_url('admin/common/test')
);

$directory_names = explode('/', $this->input->get('directory'));

foreach ($directory_names as $directory_name) {
    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $directory_name,
        'href' => base_url('admin/common/test?directory=' . $this->input->get('directory'))
    );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a solution now I found on another forum I will post on here to share

https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-68653-post-346110.html#pid346110

```
$directory_names = explode('/', $this->input->get('directory'));

$directory_done = '';

foreach ($directory_names as $directory_name) {
        $directory_done .= ($directory_done <> ''? '/':'').$directory_name; 
    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $directory_name,
        'href' => base_url('admin/common/test?directory=' . $directory_done)
    );
}
```